# When does browser read the file selected in input type=file

Tags: html

My HTML page has a `<input type="file"/>` element, and I do the following steps:

1. Click browse and select a file
2. Edit the file contents from disk
3. Click on form submit

What are the contents that are expected to go to the server in such case? Is there a definition in any spec as to what should happen (i.e the original contents should be sent, or the new contents should be sent) or is the implementation left to the browser?

Comment: I wouldn’t expect any implementation to read the file when the file is selected. What would be the reason for any implementation to do that?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on how the file input is used. However, in the most general scenario, the file content is read at the upload time.

When you execute the submit action of a form, it will go through all its elements and compose an HTTP request with all the input data. It is at this specific time the physical file on the disk is read by the form action.

Now, there are other manipulations of form submission commonly done in web applications. The file content, for example, can be read immediately by the `onChange` event of the file input element and an application can store this data in a hidden element inside the form. It may be this data embedded in the hidden element that the server is really considering.

Your non-modified data will be submitted to the server in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a simple example and found that browser keep the reference to the uploaded file.

In the nutshell:

1. Create foo.txt file
2. Add 'Hello world' content
3. Save file
4. Upload the file by using `<input type="file />`
5. *browser keeps reference to the selected file*
6. Make some changes in the file. Change 'Hello world' to 'Hello world 2'
7. Press submit button
8. The file foo.txt with 'Hello world 2' will be submitted.

You can try to test this scenario by using snippet below. Upload the file and make some changes during `setTimeout()`.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#input');

 let cache = null;

function onFileChange(event) {
 const [ file ] = event.target.files;

 cache = file;
  
  readFileData(file).then(result => {
   console.log('Result:', result);
    
    // Edit file during the timeout
    setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('File', cache);
    }, 10000)
  })
}

function readFileData(file) {
 const reader = new FileReader(file);
  
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   reader.onload = event => resolve(event.target.result);
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error)
    reader.readAsText(file);
  });
}

input.addEventListener('change', onFileChange);
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="input" type="file" />
</form>
```

Update:

Also it is possible to read data into the local variable after file has been uploaded. In such case, you will keep local copy of entire file and it will not be affected.